# Segmentation fault while using AAResultsWrapperPass in LLVM 5.0.1

Tags: llvm

I am trying to use AliasAnalysis (LLVM 5.01) and my code is as following:

```
void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
  AU.addRequired<AAResultsWrapperPass>();
}
```

And I am get the AliasAnalysis as follow:

```
AA = &getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults();
```

This code is getting compiled properly. But when I run this, I am getting following errors:

```
clang -Xclang -load -Xclang /home/zhangjun/tools/llvm/llvm-build/lib/LLVMCPI.so -O0 -c test.c 
Pass 'Unnamed pass: implement Pass::getPassName()' is not initialized.
Verify if there is a pass dependency cycle. 
Required Passes:clang-5.0: /home/zhangjun/tools/llvm/llvm/lib/IR/LegacyPassManager.cpp:653: void  llvm::PMTopLevelManager::schedulePass(llvm::Pass*): Assertion `PI && "Expected required passes to be initialized"' failed.
#0 0x0000000002dae43f llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) /home/zhangjun/tools/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:398:0
#1 0x0000000002dae4d0 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) /home/zhangjun/tools/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:462:0
#2 0x0000000002dac916 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() /home/zhangjun/tools/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Signals.cpp:49:0
#3 0x0000000002daddd7 SignalHandler(int) /home/zhangjun/tools/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:252:0
```

Some one propose passing current function as argument to this function to solve this issue ([Segmentation fault while using AAResultsWrapperPass in llvm3.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033274/segmentation-fault-while-using-aaresultswrapperpass-in-llvm3-8-1))

```
getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults() - NOT working
getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults(F)- working
```

However, his method does not work for me. How to deal with this problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `getAnalysis` with the function as the parameter, i.e.

```
getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>(F).getAAResults();
```